# How does the "UseRouting" method work in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've read that `UseRouting` matches a request to an endpoint, and `UseEndpoints` executes the matched endpoint. However, we have middleware in this order:

```
// ..some other middleware

UseRouting(); 

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Map("/something", (context) => context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"));

// some nother middleware
```

So, how can the `UseRouting` method match a request (like `https://localhost:5000/Home/Index`) to endpoints (like `/Home/Index`) if it invoked before `MapControllerRoute`?

In other words, how does the `UseRouting` method know about this endpoint (`/Home/Index`) to make the comparison?

I haven't tried anything because this is a theoretical question

Comment: It gets the information from the URL that client uses to connect to the website : https://localhost:5000/Home/Index.  An HTTP Request has three parts 1) URL 2) HTTP Header(s) 3) Body.  The URL is part of the connection information.

Answer (score 1):

**UseRouting** adds route matching to the middleware pipeline. This middleware looks at the set of endpoints defined in the app, and selects the best match based on the request.

The endpoint is always null before UseRouting is called.If a match is found, the endpoint is non-null between UseRouting and UseEndpoints.The UseRouting middleware uses the [SetEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.setendpoint?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method to attach the endpoint to the current context.The UseEndpoints middleware is designed to be used in tandem with the UseRouting middleware.

```
// Location 1: before routing runs, endpoint is always null here.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"1. Endpoint: {context.GetEndpoint()?.DisplayName ?? "(null)"}");
    await next(context);
});

app.UseRouting();

// Location 2: after routing runs, endpoint will be non-null if routing found a match.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"2. Endpoint: {context.GetEndpoint()?.DisplayName ?? "(null)"}");
    await next(context);
});

// Location 3: runs when this endpoint matches
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

result:

[image]

You can read [ASP.NET Core endpoint definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#aspnet-core-endpoint-definition) to know more.